# How to manage dagger2 component creation and storage

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

A long time i have been struggling with dagger components. 
At first i made `Injectors` class for each **custom scoped** component which contained static field either with `WeakReference<Component>` or just a `Component`, so that i always had an access to this component through static method.

But i think thats a pretty bad approach because `WeakReference` could be cleared so you will not get the same `Component`, as well as you can just forget to clear `Component` in static field.

I designed another approach when i have `ComponentsHolder` interface which is implemented by App and contains some methods to add, delete, and check if component exists in a `HashMap<String, Component>` inside the same App class.

So this approach combined with kotlin extensions for `Context` gave me a great opportunity to inject thing anywhere i have `Context` like this:

```
context.injector(Component::class) {
   inject(this@ObjectWhereToInject)
}
```

So i mind maybe i doing something wrong? Or is there a better approach to store and retrieve dagger components?